# Rails 4 - json.jbuilder with remotipart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, remotipart

My Application details

1. Rails 4.0 application
2. Remotipart `gem remotipart (1.2.1)`
3. Using json.jbuilder to return a response.
4. Using paperclip gem for uploading file `paperclip (~> 4.1)`

I have a form with `remote: true` and `multipart: true`. I am redering a json.jbuilder template after submitting the form. I have `ajax:success`callback on the form.

When I submit a form without an attachment then it renders json.jbuilder template and  `ajax:success` callback works. But if I submit a form with an attachment then the form gets submitted rendering json.jbuilder file. But the `ajax:success` callback doesn't work.

I have been struggling with this issue since 2 days.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use

```
hidden_field "format", :json
```

But it didn't work. After adding option

```
:'data-type' => :json
```

for the `form_for`it worked.